# Lucene: how to boost some specific field

Tags: lucene, search-engine

In my case, documents have two fields, for example, "title" and "views". "views" is represented the num of times that people have visited this document. like: "title":"iphone", "views":"10". 
I have to develop a strategy that will assign some weights to views, such as the relevance score is calculated by score(title)*0.8+score(views)*0.2. Does lucene can do this? And I want to know whether there are some algorithms related to this question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is how you can do that:

```
Query titleQuery, viewsQuery;

titleQuery.setBoost(0.8);
viewsQuery.setBoost(0.2);
BooleanQuery query = new BooleanQuery();
query.add(titleQuery, Occur.MUST); // or Occur.SHOULD if this clause is optional
query.add(viewsQuery, Occur.SHOULD); // or Occur.MUST if this clause is required

// use query to search documents
```

The score will be proportional to `0.8*score(titleQuery) + 0.2*score(viewsQuery)` (to a multiplicative constant).

To leverage your `views` field, you will probably need to use a [ValueSourceQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/function/ValueSourceQuery.html).

Comment: if I understand it correctyl setBoost has been deprecated and these days https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/BoostQuery.html shoudl be used

Answer (score 22):

If you get here after 2020, in Lucene 8.5.2.

1. Document.setBoost() doesn't exist anymore.
2. Field.setBoost() doesn't exist anymore.
3. Query.setBoost() doesn't exist anymore.

The ways to go:

1. Wrap your Query (any Query but probably TermQuery in this case) in à BoostQuery

   ```
   Query boosted = new BoostQuery(query, 2f);
   ```
2. Use the caret ^ symbol in your query parser syntax.
3. Specify boosts in MultiFiledQueryParser.
4. Use PerFieldSimilarityWrapper and adjust score per field.

Answer (score 9):

You can boost in 3 ways. Depending on your needs you might want to employ a combination

> Document level boosting - while indexing - by calling
> document.setBoost() before a document is added to the index.
>
> Document's Field level boosting - while indexing - by calling
> field.setBoost() before adding a field to the document (and before
> adding the document to the index).
>
> Query level boosting - during
> search, by setting a boost on a query clause, calling
> Query.setBoost().

source: http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_0/scoring.html

Comment: document.setBoost() is deprecated long time ago.