# Setting priority in lucene.net results

Tags: sorting, lucene.net

I am using a `Lucene.Net` query like this

```
(PropertyID:1 OR PropertyID:25 OR PropertyID:5 OR PropertyID:10 OR PropertyID:15)
```

I want result from `Lucene.Net` in order of `PropertyId`. I passed for example first record should be for `PropertyId` 1 second for 25 and third for 5. But currently `Lucene.Net` arranging result set in different way.

Comment: Can you show what order is it being returned in?

Comment: it is random order so each time this returns different order.

Answer (score 0):

The order of fields in the query has no effect on sorting.

There are 2 ways to achieve the sorting you're looking for:

1. Use [boosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9829161/lucene-how-to-boost-some-specific-field) in your query. You can boost PropertyID:1 higher than the rest so that these matches are scored higher and thus appear first in the results, then score PropertyID:2 second highest, etc. For example:
   `(PropertyID:1^5 OR PropertyID:25^4 OR PropertyID:5^3 OR PropertyID:10^2 OR PropertyID:15)` This is simple to implement but may not work right if you're including other criteria in your query because that other criteria will affecting the scoring.
2. Implement custom sorting via your own Comparator class. This may take quite a bit of work especially given the lack of resources on the web for doing this, however it will give you the greatest control over your sorting. Here is [an example of a custom Comparator](http://blog.tremend.ro/2007/05/17/a-z-0-9-custom-sorting-in-lucene/) used to sort by a string value alphabetically that may be a good place for you to start.