# Lucene.net Negation clause is not working

Tags: full-text-search, lucene.net

I am very much new to Lucene.net and though I am not able to achieve basic functionality i.e. Not in.

My requirement is to search "road?construction" without "Works" word.

e.g.

Main Road Construction Works -- Invalid

Road Construction And Maintenance Services -- Valid (Doesn't contains word Works)

Please refer my code below.

```
string searchQuery = "\"road?construction\"*";
    BooleanQuery query2 = new BooleanQuery();
    Query query;
                try
                {
                    query = parser.Parse(searchQuery.Trim());
                }
                catch (ParseException)
                {
                    query = parser.Parse(QueryParser.Escape(searchQuery.Trim()));
                }
                            
                query2.Add(query,Occur.SHOULD);
                query2.Add(new BooleanClause(new TermQuery (new Term("Name", "Works")), Occur.MUST_NOT));
```

This still gets both above mentioned record in to search result. I wish to cut invalid record(first).

[image]

Here is the result query generated in backend.

Please suggest workaround.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why your putting wildcard characters into the phrase. If you're looking for "road construction" then that's all you need. If you are looking to allow some variations then maybe a "slop phrase" is what you need ie. "road construction"~2. The number part allows for n "operations" like n additional words inbetween.

Here's a set of tests that show your examples (TestExpr2, TestExpr3) and some working variations (TestExpr1 and TestQuery).

Hope this helps

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest7
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestExpr1()
    {
        TestExpr("\"road construction\" -works");
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestExpr2()
    {
        TestExpr("\"road?construction\"* -works");
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestExpr3()
    {
        TestExpr(QueryParser.Escape("\"road?construction\"* -works"));
    }

    private void TestExpr(string expr)
    {
        var writer = CreateIndex();
        Add(writer, "Main Road Construction Works");
        Add(writer, "Road Construction And Maintenance Services");
        writer.Flush(true, true, true);
        var searcher = new IndexSearcher(writer.GetReader());

        var result = Search(searcher, expr);

        Assert.AreEqual(1, result.Count);
        Assert.IsTrue(result.Contains("Road Construction And Maintenance Services"));
        writer.Dispose();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestQuery()
    {
        var writer = CreateIndex();
        Add(writer, "Main Road Construction Works");
        Add(writer, "Road Construction And Maintenance Services");
        writer.Flush(true, true, true);
        var searcher = new IndexSearcher(writer.GetReader());

        var query = new BooleanQuery();
        var p = new PhraseQuery();
        p.Add(new Term("name", "road"));
        p.Add(new Term("name", "construction"));
        query.Add(p, Occur.MUST);
        query.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("name", "works")), Occur.MUST_NOT);

        var result = Search(searcher, query);

        Assert.AreEqual(1, result.Count);
        Assert.IsTrue(result.Contains("Road Construction And Maintenance Services"));
        writer.Dispose();
    }

    private List<string> Search(IndexSearcher searcher, string expr)
    {
        var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30);
        var queryParser = new QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, "name", analyzer);
        var query = queryParser.Parse(expr);
        return Search(searcher, query);
    }

    private List<string> Search(IndexSearcher searcher, Query query)
    {
        var collector = TopScoreDocCollector.Create(10, true);
        searcher.Search(query, collector);
        var result = new List<string>();
        var matches = collector.TopDocs().ScoreDocs;
        foreach (var item in matches)
        {
            var id = item.Doc;
            var doc = searcher.Doc(id);
            result.Add(doc.GetField("name").StringValue);
        }

        return result;
    }

    IndexWriter CreateIndex()
    {
        var directory = new RAMDirectory();
        var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30);
        var writer = new IndexWriter(directory, analyzer, new IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength(1000));
        return writer;
    }

    void Add(IndexWriter writer, string text)
    {
        var document = new Document();
        document.Add(new Field("name", text, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
        writer.AddDocument(document);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply Andy. You provided great explanation. It really helped me. I've a problem with current search is that, when I search for "road construction", it should also search "Construction of Road" (Both are same). How to achieve this?

Comment: Use a "slop phrase" query like `"road construction"~2`. This allows 2 "operations" on the terms in the phrase. So there could be 2 terms inbetween or a reorder and 1 term inbetween. Kind of like and "AND" (BooleanQuery with MUST) but defining how "close" the terms need to be. Increase 2 as necessary for your needs. But you shouldn't need it to be too big otherwise you'll start to get unexpected results.

Comment: "road construction"~3 worked for me. Thanks a lot Andy. You are master mind.

Comment: One more question, how to get control over Rank provided by Lucene? My problem is sometimes lucene is not getting more important results on top. I heard about boosts but not have much idea about it. Thanks.

Comment: now you're asking the difficult questions!! Ordering is often a "problem". But, how do you define what is "important"? It may seem obvious to a human but actually very hard to create a good algorithm. Several options are available: https://blog.imaginea.com/understanding-lucene-boosting-part-1/ is a pretty good explanation of boost. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9829161/lucene-how-to-boost-some-specific-field is an example in code; Or create a "score" at index time and use a Sort when querying; Or Sort by date (if that's important). Or retrieve a lot of docs then sort them; Or...