# How do I boost queries in Lucene 7?

Tags: java, lucene

I want to boost a query in Lucene 7. In the previous versions (< 6) I was just using the setBoost(float boost) method. i.e.

```
TermQuery termQuery = new TermQuery(new Term("field", "value"));
termQuery.setBoost(2);
```

In Lucene 7 there is only a method that contains the boost as a parameter:

```
public Weight createWeight(IndexSearcher searcher,
                       boolean needsScores,
                       float boost)
```

which isn't the method responsible for the boost!
Do you know how to apply the boosting to the queries?

Comment: This example may help https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2021/07/lucene-boosting-queries.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All queries are now immutable, which also extends to boosts, per [LUCENE-6590](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-6590). As such, to apply boosts you would use a [BoostQuery](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/BoostQuery.html) to wrap the query. Like this:

```
Query termQuery = new TermQuery(new Term("field", "value"));
Query boostedTermQuery = new BoostQuery(termQuery, 2);
```

Comment: Ther are other ways if you are interested https://stackoverflow.com/a/62328934/731548