# Ho to use FunctionScoreQuery with text fields?

Tags: lucene, scoring, lucene-boosting

In Lucene 6.6.0, index-time boosting is deprecated. Moreover, also CustomQueryScore is deprecated. So, Lucene developers advice is to use FunctionScoreQuery. However, I can't understand how to boost text field with FunctionScoreQuery, since it takes as input DoubleValuesSource, which helps to boost just numerical fields (fromIntField, fromDoubleField etc...)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are misunderstanding the guidance they are giving there. You index the *boost* in a docValues field, not the text. Think of the boost as sort of a meta-field. So you end up with two fields, something like:

- a text field, `myField`
- a numeric DocValues field, `myFieldBoost`

And you would query the contents of myField, and factor the value of myFieldBoost into your FunctionScoreQuery.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. First of all, FunctionScoreQuery takes as input DoubleValuesSource and not DocValues. Secondly, how to build a DocValues instance from myField?

Comment: you do not have to build a DocValues instance from your field. this is an additional field on your lucene document which includes the score value. so this are two separate fields and with the FunctionScoreQuery you have to say which query (including your normal field) and which DoubleValuesSource (including your DocValues field) are used.

Comment: Are there any example anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Boosting while searching is a better solution and can be done with :

- [BoostQuery](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/BoostQuery.html)
- with a boost set on the field:
  [Lucene: how to boost some specific field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9829161/lucene-how-to-boost-some-specific-field)

For basic understanding how scoring works have a lock at the [documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/package-summary.html#scoringBasics)

Comment: With this solution, you have to split the query by fields. I don't know which kind of query I'll receive: plain text or query class, so I'd rather go with a more general solution.

Comment: then you have to consider the answer of femtoRgon

Answer (score 0):

It might be too late, but check the discussions here: http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/any-example-on-FunctionScoreQuery-since-Field-setBoost-is-deprecated-with-Lucene-6-6-0-td4400355.html, and some copy and paste of how to use the FunctionScoreQuery class:

Example that sorts based on an expression:

```
// compile an expression:
Expression expr = JavascriptCompiler.compile("sqrt(_score) + ln(popularity)");

// SimpleBindings just maps variables to SortField instances
SimpleBindings bindings = new SimpleBindings();
bindings.add(new SortField("_score", SortField.Type.SCORE));
bindings.add(new SortField("popularity", SortField.Type.INT));

// create a sort field and sort by it (reverse order)
Sort sort = new Sort(expr.getSortField(bindings, true));
Query query = new TermQuery(new Term("body", "contents"));
searcher.search(query, 10, sort);
```

Example that modifies the scores produced by the query:

```
// compile an expression:
Expression expr = JavascriptCompiler.compile("sqrt(_score) + ln(popularity)");

// SimpleBindings just maps variables to SortField instances
SimpleBindings bindings = new SimpleBindings();
bindings.add(new SortField("_score", SortField.Type.SCORE));
bindings.add(new SortField("popularity", SortField.Type.INT));

// create a query that matches based on body:contents but
// scores using expr
Query query = new FunctionScoreQuery(
    new TermQuery(new Term("body", "contents")),
    expr.getDoubleValuesSource(bindings));
searcher.search(query, 10);
```

The Lucene Expression class accepts Javascript expressions: 
(https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_7_2/expressions/org/apache/lucene/expressions/js/package-summary.html)

"A Javascript expression is a numeric expression specified using an expression syntax that's based on JavaScript expressions. You can construct expressions using:

- Integer, floating point, hex and octal literals
- Arithmetic operators: `+ - * / %`
- Bitwise operators: `| & ^ ~ << >> >>>`
- Boolean operators (including the ternary operator): `&& || ! ?:`
- Comparison operators: `< <= == >= >`
- Common mathematic functions: `abs ceil exp floor ln log10 logn max min sqrt pow`
- Trigonometric library functions: `acosh acos asinh asin atanh atan atan2 cosh cos sinh sin tanh tan`
- Distance functions: `haversin`
- Miscellaneous functions: `min, max`
- Arbitrary external variables" - see the above Bindings examples